# Titanium - android app store build error

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've built to the Android app store problem free for the past couple of years, but recently I started receiving this error:

Android SDK version 4.4.2 not found.

I can build to the Genymotion emulator with no problem as well, the problem is exclusive to Android app store builds.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="6001" android:versionName="6.0.1">
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

--

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.3
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17179869184
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.5
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.1.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/keithtucci/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.1.2.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
Command
```

[Android SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0VW.png)

Comment: As a followup question, I am primarily developing for iOS so excuse the my lack of Android build knowledge.  My goal is to build using Ti SDK 5.1.2 or later that support the Android 4.4 or greater.  With that do I only need the install Android 6.0 (23) build tools or do i need all of the build tools for 4.4 - 6.0...?

Comment: There's several things to the Android SDK. There's the tools & build tools, which you should always use the [latest Appcelerator supports](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-RequiredAndroidPackages). Then there's the API level. Every level includes the APIs of previous levels down to a minimum version. Titanium currently requires 23 because we use Material Design theme. It will run on 4.4 phones just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install API 23 since this is what you (and also 5.1.2 by default) target but from the screenshot seems to be not installed.

Comment: So I could just install the build tools for API 23 only, and there's no need for the earlier APIs to be installed if I am building off 5.1.2.

Comment: As a followup, I did reinstall Android from scratch with just API 23 and I am able to build now, thanks.  Though when I try to run the Genymotion emulator i get the error:  Android SDK version 4.4 not found.  I am running against google nexus 5x api 23.  Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

i had API 23 installad, to solve I open .settings\com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.prefs file in project dir and remove those lines:

```
android/abi=armeabi-v7a
android/abi.type=String

android/sdk_version=4.4.2
android/sdk_version.type=String
```